# Copying contents of directories

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I created a directory 'Skeleton' inside another directory 'Projects'. I then added some files named bin, docs, NAME and tests inside Skeleton. Then I created another directory 'NewSkeleton' inside 'Projects' and tried copying the contents of 'Skeleton' to 'NewSkeleton' using

xcopy Skeleton NewSkeleton\ /s

All the files were copied, except bin. Could anyone explain why that happened, and suggest a better way to copy?

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to add that I had been working on cmd. I have edited the question. Apologies.

Comment: xcopy Skeleton NewSkeleton /E. Is bin directory empty?

Comment: What is `bin`, a file or a directory? what are the attributes?

Comment: bin is a directory inside the Skeleton directory, and yes, it is empty